# How can I move my old sites from shared host server to VPS?

Tags: linux, laravel, vps, shared-hosting, digital-ocean

I'm sure a lot of you guys used to be in the same situation as I am at right now.

**Before**

I used to owned shared hosting for about 2 years. 
I kind of get used to it, whenever I create a new site. 
I just need to upload my entire new folder including : index.html , styles, scripts, and other assets via FTP into the root directory to my shared host server. Then, I go to the url of that folder, I will see the site loaded, that's how I normally do it.

---

**Now**

I upgrade the way I host my site. I just recently purchased a VPS on Digital Ocean, and run Laravel application on it. Now, the site is way faster, and I have more control.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what to do with all my old sites that I used to have.

- How do move them into my new VPS ?
- How do I go to them ? How is that work ?
- Should I create a `public_html` folder or something ?
- How can I achieve something like this ?

Any direction on this will be much appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your setup (single domain, multi-domain). If you're dealing with a single domain environment you'll just move everything over like normal. If you're in a multi-domain environment you'll need to point all your domains to the new server and setup different apache sites (config files) that point to their respective locations on disk.

In my experience with multi-domain environments and Apache 2.4 it's best to have */var/www/* be your center where you can store your .htpasswd or any other files like that, and a folder named *public* which has your outward facing websites in their subfolders.

Example:

web1.com would exist in /var/www/public/web1.com/...
web2.com would exist in /var/www/public/web2.com/...

You could alternatively have another public folder, but if you're specifically asking about laravel you'd want to point the apache config to the public directory as if you go any higher people have access to your .env file.

If you have everything in your single domain environment (public_html) and you now have a laravel site at your root you could alias a specific path to act as your "old site" data that points to a different folder than your laravel install.

Comment: Thank-you for all of these information. But I have some questions for you.

Comment: 1. I shoud create `www/public/` in my `var` directory. right ?

Comment: 2. You said, I could alias specific path to act as my old site. Do you mind tell me about that a little more ?

Comment: Yes, creating a www/public/ makes it easier to organize public/private data. I have my websites currently setup in my home directory and symlink the /var/www/public/<site> to ~/www/public/<site> so I can divy up websites per user and not have to worry about them in the /var folder.

As for aliasing you can check it out (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html), essentially you have in your .conf file an alias "old" that points to a specific directory outside of your laravel install. i.e Alias "/old" "/var/www/public/old/..."